# Can't rely on indexes in chrome.tabs.move

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I have tabs like this:

- tab A
- tab B
- tab C
- tab D
- tab E

to move **tab A** after **tab C** I use

```
chrome.tabs.move(tabA.id, {'index': tabC.index+1});
```

but I get it after **tab D**
If I move any tab from down to up in the list, it works fine, but if "upper" tab is moved down, indexes get messed (upper tab is removed from indexes list and target index is down by 1)
Do I need to somehow compare moved tab index and target index and based on that calculate resulting index (if A < C) or is there easier solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had some experiences with the Chrome API too, and if there's one thing I learned, then it's that the API just behaves as it does.
If new indices get assigned to tabs before the current one is inserted, but after it's been removed, then that's just that.
It's probably best to just go with a check like you suggested:

```
function moveAfter(what, target)
{
    target = (typeof target === 'number' target : target.index) + 1;
    if(what.constructor === Array.prototype.constructor)
    {
        var w = [];
        var t = target;
        for(var i = 0; i < what.length)
        {
            if(what[i].index < target)
            {
                t--;
            }
            w.push(what[i].id);
        }
        what = w;
        target = t;
    }
    else
    {
        if(what.index < target)
        {
            target--;
        }
        what = what.id;
    }
    chrome.tabs.move(what, {index: target});
}
```

`what` can be a `Tab` object or an array of `Tab`s.
`target` can be a `Tab` object or a tab index (without the `+1`).

Comment: this test looks nice. Is this going to work if i move array (tabs.move accepts array for moved IDs)..EDIT: no ofc it won't work

Comment: @kl123 Changed my snippet. `what` can be a single `Tab` or an array of such, but not an array of ids, because the indices of the tabs are required too.

Comment: I figured something similar. I set counter to target index, and in one loop I'm testing moved indexes against target index If it is lower than target I decrease value of counter, and use that counter asindex: counter+1. So far in testing everything is fine (with array too)

Answer (score 1):

this is what I ended up with:
I have array called **moved** in which I have objects

```
moved = [{id, index}, {id, index}.....]
```

I can set whatever I want on user action when move starts, so I'm collecting id's and indexes

On target tab where my **moved** tab(s) should go (after it) I have this:

```
    var counter = this.index;
    for (var i=moved.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (moved[i].ix < counter) {
            counter--;
            chrome.tabs.move(moved[i].id, {'index': counter+1});    
        } else if (moved[i].ix > counter) chrome.tabs.move(moved[i].id, {'index': counter+1});
    }
```

it's actually very simple and works fine

Answer (score 0):

> I get it after tab D

This is because you are trying to move to `tabC.index+1` which is 4, then removing tab A, results in `B, C, D, E` and moving to index 4 results in `B, C, D, A, E` which is A after D.  does that make sense?

So if the tab you wish to move after tab C is before tab C, then do not use the `+1` bit, otherwise you should use it.

Comment: yea, I understand why is it happening, just not sure how to fix it. So your advice is to test it if moved tab is from somewhere UP and then calculate index?